# What is the purpose of "Your vote has been recorded" popup which appears after close vote?

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, user-experience

I keep seeing a blue "Your vote has been recorded" popup after casting close-votes.

I *know* that votes are recorded - it has been that way for years. The popup requires me to click a small [x] sign on it to close - clicking elsewhere on the page doesn't work. It is extremely annoying.

What is the purpose of this? How can I get rid of that thing?

[image: popup]

*It looks like this after clicking on the text. It covers useful content on page.*

Comment: sometimes you may get error due to *your vote not being recorded* so this is a basic confirmation

Comment: I suppose you could create a user script that check the string in the message and auto-dismisses it unless there's an error. It's a bit sad that one needs to do this though. I thought about doing it for up/down voting, since I'm ever only interested in knowing if I only have a few votes left.

Comment: Also reported here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361106/unnecessary-feedback-banner-on-close-voting-and-flagging

Comment: This notification has existed for a long time, but previously, it was less visible because the "Your vote has been recorded" appeared under the Close button.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, it has not been so obtrusive

Comment: Indeed, I think the previous location was better. It's good feedback to have if you care, but it doesn't need to be across the top of the page.

Comment: I hate its new location. Very distracting and confused the heck out of me today. I actually clicked to dismiss it I was so thrown. I then got quite grumpy for a short time :-)

Comment: *It is extremely annoying* - took me just two votes and I already hate it. I will not vote anymore until this thing is fixed.